# Writing a code without using any python libraries or built in python functions and using an unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing

Hello I am struggling in my AI class right now we are working on this homework pertaining to python and unit testing. Here is the homework question:

Without using any python libraries or built in python functions:

- Show you can do the necessary research to lookup the formula for mode
  and standard deviation
- Write a function that returns the "mode" from a list
- Write a function that returns the standard deviation of the list
- Write unit tests for both functions that cover all use cases

Here is what I have so far, just don't know if it's done correctly.

```
def mode(num):
    count = dict()
    mode = False
    mode_int = 0
    result = 0
    for x in num:
        if not count.get(x):
            count[x] = 1
        else:
            count[x] += 1
            mode = True
            if count[x] > mode_int:
                mode_int = count[x]
                result = x
    if mode:
        return result
    else:
        return "There was no mode"
```

```
def standard_deviation(num):
    total = 0
    for x in num:
        total += x
    m = total/len(num)
    size = len(num)
    i = 0
    sum = 0
    while i < size:
        sum += (num[i] - m) * (num[i] - m)
        i += 1
    sum = sum / (size - 1)
    return sum**0.5
```

Comment: you have to write `unit tests` to check `if it's done correctly.` :)

Comment: I wouldn't use `return "There was no mode"` but `return None` - it will be universal.

Comment: so now create some example data with expected results and run it - `mode(data) == expected_result`. You can create many examples and put on list and use `for`-loop to test function with all examples.

Comment: more popular is `if x not in count:` instead of `if not count.get(x):`

Comment: `if not count.get(x)` is wrong here, because of what happens if x is 0.